# How to make CSS2DObject scale with zooming

Tags: javascript, three.js

I currently use CSS2DObjects using the [CSS2DRenderer](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/renderers/CSS2DRenderer) to display text in my visualization. I would now like that text to scale with zooming. In other words, when zooming out I want the text to get smaller and when zooming in I want the text to get bigger. How would one go about achiving this?

My code to create the object:

```
const p = document.createElement('p');
p.textContent = "Hello World";
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.appendChild(p)
const divContainer = new CSS2DObject(div)
divContainer.position.set(0, 0, 0)
scene.add(divContainer)
```

I use `OrbitControls` with a `PerspectiveCamera`.